# How to enable and expose specific endpoints in a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two endpoints /users and /groups
However, I want only the /users endpoint to be accessible in a given profile
Could I specify which ones I want to enable, for example through application.properties?

With the use of @Profiles it worked but I want to know if it is possible to concentrate this in one place like in application.properties

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is in some way more centralized, but same could be achieved by grouping the  methods per profile under same class and adding the profile annotation there.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/hello-dev")
  public String helloDev() {
    return "Hello from dev";
  }

  @GetMapping("/hello-prod")
  public String helloProd() {
    return "Hello from prod";
  }

  @Configuration
  @Profile("prod")
  static class ProdConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer prodWebMvcConfigurer() {
      return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addRedirectViewController("/hello", "/hello-prod");
        }
      };
    }
  }

  @Configuration
  @Profile("dev")
  static class DevConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer devWebMvcConfigurer() {
      return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addRedirectViewController("/hello", "/hello-dev");
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if you look at the example, you could technically extract the endpoint values to `application.properties` and then use it in your `@Configuration`, but I wouldn't go to that extent.